# How to modify my Schema or Query, so it runs effectively?

Tags: sql

In a interview I was asked " You have a table with huge data but there is a requirement to view the rows that have been added in the last 15 minutes. How do you do this effectively without having to query the whole table as it takes so long".

I have said that I will create a view to have the latest 1000 records(Here I am assuming that there were less than a 1000 records cretaed in last 15 min) and I would query the view rather than the entire table. The interviewer was okay but he said there is a better approach and I am not able to find it.

Comment: make an index on the created_at column?

Comment: thank you.. I wasn't aware of the concept of indexed... or atleast couldn't recollect..

Comment: ok, then i will add that answer

Comment: Great! Do you mind elaborating on why creating a view and querying the same is not a good approach.

Comment: Because when you create the view, you need a full scan table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make an index for the created_at column, this will avoid scanning the whole table and will considerably improve performance

Comment: To expand on this answer: An index helps to speed up SELECT queries and WHERE clauses, but it slows down data input, with the UPDATE and the INSERT statements.  If you find yourself using the same WHERE [ColumnName] statement multiple times (or you have performance issues) you may want to consider an index on that column.  If you find yourself using multiple WHERE conditions consistently you may want to consider a composite index.

Answer (score -2):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT columns
FROM table
WHERE DATE_ADD(last_seen, INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) >= NOW();
```

Or:

```
select *
from my_table
where my_column > timestamp '2020-10-09 00:00:05' - numtodsinterval(15,'MINUTE')
```

I am not sure aboutthe db you are using.

This goes 15 minutes back from last seen.

Comment: your query will still scan the whole table

Comment: The first query will have very low performance, unless there's a very specific custom index on it (unlikely). The second one has potential, but needs improvement.